# Jenkins container - invalid reference format

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, docker, jenkins

I'm running this in Powershell on Windows 10.  I'm not understanding this error.  Is it in relation to the -v arguments or does it have something to do with my pathing?

*note - the which command has been aliased from Powershell

```
 docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -p 8080:8080 myjenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

In the window you need to mention `//` in `/var/run/docker.sock` or if updated version then it will work with a single slash. For CI this is enough `/var/run/docker.sock`. You do not need to mount bin folder.
and in Powershell will be `${which docker}`

```
docker run -d -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ${which docker}:/usr/bin/docker -p 8080:8080 myjenkins
```